# Need to add value to populate dropdown

Tags: jquery, arrays, html-select, key-value

Please see the link : http://jsfiddle.net/NaUAL/

Result :

```
<select id="second-choice">
<option>Chips</option>
<option>Cookies</option>
</select>
```

Desire Result :

```
<select id="second-choice">
<option value="1">Chips</option>
<option value="2">Cookies</option>
</select>
```

I need a way to add value to dropdown.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need to add value to populate dropdown via manual data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19119190/need-to-add-value-to-populate-dropdown-via-manual-data)

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NaUAL/57/)

changed

```
html.push('<option value="'+ ++i+'">' + val + '</option>');
```

added `value` attribute.

`++i`  as index starts from `0` and you need value to start from `1`

in

```
$.each(vals, function (i, val) {
    html.push('<option value="'+ ++i+'">' + val + '</option>');
});
```

Comment: thanks but is there a way to add value to data ? 

base": ["Please choose from above"],
        "beverages": ["Coffee", "Coke"],
        "snacks": ["Chips", "Cookies"]

Comment: @SyedSaadImran you should make it a new question.