# Need to add value to populate dropdown via manual data

Tags: jquery, arrays, html-select, key-value

Please see the link : http://jsfiddle.net/NaUAL/

Result :

```
<select id="second-choice">
<option>Chips</option>
<option>Cookies</option>
</select>
```

Desire Result :

```
<select id="second-choice">
<option value="465">Chips</option>
<option value="984">Cookies</option>
</select>
```

I need a way to add value to data and get similar output ... value should be listed in the following data :
"base": ["Please choose from above"], "beverages": ["Coffee", "Coke"], "snacks": ["Chips", "Cookies"]

Comment: Where does the 465, 984 comes from?

Comment: they should be added in the data, i dont know that exact format to add the values :

"snacks": ["Chips" "465" , "Cookies" "984"]

same location as the data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need to add value to populate dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19118633/need-to-add-value-to-populate-dropdown)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/NaUAL/59/)

```
var data = {
        "base" : ["Please choose from above"],
        "beverages": ["Coffee_465","Coke_984"],
        "snacks": ["Chips_123","Cookies_987"]
}
```

assign data key value like  `optionText_optionValue`

and

```
$.each(vals,function(i,val){
    var v = val.split('_'); //use split to break optionText and optionValue
    html.push('<option value="'+v[1]+'">'+v[0]+'</option>')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(vals,function(i,val)
{
   html.push('<option value='+value_variable+'>'+val+'</option>'); // value variable contains the actual value such as 465 or 984 or whatever.
});
```

Comment: maybe show an example of data with values in it ...

var data = {
    "base": ["Please choose from above"],
        "beverages": ["Coffee", "Coke"],
        "snacks": ["Chips", "Cookies"]
}